# Como configurar FTP PHP - Ajuda

Tags: php, conexão, ftp

Ao utilizar o WinSCP executo os seguinte passos: (dados ficticiosos)

**hostname: bala.rimunivert.com.br**
**username: zzzzzzz@rjozzz000**

depois disso ele pede 
Gateway username: juliohenrique
Gateway password: 1234566

e depois disso ainda aparece: futher authentical required
e ai eu coloco outra senha: blablabalaba

ou seja pelo que eu entendo para acessar esse servidor eu preciso me autenticar em outro primeiro. A duvida que me gera é a seguinte, como implementar isso nesse meu codigo ?

```
//esse é um metodo de conexao da minha classe ftp
public function connect ($server, $ftpUser, $ftpPassword, $isPassive = false){

    // *** Set up basic connection
    $this->connectionId = ftp_connect($server);

    // *** Login with username and password
    $loginResult = ftp_login($this->connectionId, $ftpUser, $ftpPassword);

    // *** Sets passive mode on/off (default off)
    ftp_pasv($this->connectionId, $isPassive);

    // *** Check connection
    if ((!$this->connectionId) || (!$loginResult)) {
        $this->logMessage('FTP connection has failed!');
        $this->logMessage('Attempted to connect to ' . $server . ' for user ' . $ftpUser, true);
        return false;
    } else {
        $this->logMessage('Connected to ' . $server . ', for user ' . $ftpUser);
        $this->loginOk = true;
        return true;
    }
}

//minhas constantes definidas
define('FTP_HOST', 'bala.rimunivert.com.br');
define('FTP_USER', 'juliohenrique');
define('FTP_PASS', '1234566');

//como eu chamo esse metodo e algum arquivo
$ftpObj -> connect(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
```

Esse código daria certo se eu não tivesse que me autenticar em outro servidor antes de acessar o servidor que eu quero. Não sei se ficou claro, mas alguem pode me ajudar a como devo fazer essa conexão?

como eu consigo me conectar para enviar arquivos nesse tipo de rede ?

**Pessoal, alguem me da um luz! pelo winscp eu conecto marcando a opção SFTP, o que isso significa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acessar um servidor no meio da conexão utilize a biblioteca [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). Contudo, dessa forma você não conseguirá utilizar as funções nativas de FTP do PHP, terá que trabalhar como se estivesse em uma linha de comando (o que na prática é isso mesmo).

Da forma que apresentei acima você utilizará o cliente de FTP do servidor intermediário dessa conexão.

Exemplo de como executar phpseclib: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php

Comment: Será que não tem alguma maneira de fazer isso utilizando somente as funções nativas do PHP?

Comment: Desconheço outra forma, o servidor que está executando seu código PHP tem que ter acesso ao servidor de FTP seja diretamente ou com um proxy, mas quero acompanhar se algum ninja sabe mais sobre isso..

Comment: não consigo acessar essa lib o proxy aqui bloqueia haha, terei que ver em casa.

Comment: Certo, aproveita e faz um desenho da arquitetura dessa rede, assim poderemos ajudar mais!!

Comment: pelo que eu entendi aqui é apenas um proxy que precisa ser autenticado antes de acessar ao ftp do servidor. Você acha que com phpseclib eu consigo fazer isso?

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 é por isso que pedi a arquitetura, eu entendi que existe um servidor no meio que tem acesso ao servidor com FTP. Isso é muito comum em redes corporativas, mas se for um proxy dá para utilizar funções nativas do PHP